# How did Tony Stark disable the Hulk during "World War Hulk"?

Tags: comics, marvel, the-incredible-hulk

In World War Hulk, Tony Stark somehow aims a satellite at the Hulk and disables him, turning him back into Bruce Banner. How did he aim the satellite? How did the laser (?) stop the Hulk, who was at the peak of his rage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking for a picture to explain the panel I meant I came across this on wikipedia:

> In the 2010 "World War Hulks" storyline, it is revealed that **the satellites used to revert Hulk back to Banner at the end of "World War Hulk" siphoned off the gamma radiation from his body**...

So it turns out the laser didn't do extra damage to the Hulk but it just siphoned off his innate gamma radiation. And it references: *"Who is the Red Hulk?" Hulk v2, 1 (August 2010), Marvel Comics*

Comment: Also, it should be noted that Banner essentially gave up after the fight with Sentinel. It's highly unlikely the laser would have stopped him otherwise.